# :last selector doesn't find last element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having an issue with the `:last` selector, which I am trying to use in the following fiddle to find the last div-Element.

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("div:last").after("<div> new Row</div>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6sMV7/8/

Clicking on the button doesn't add a "new row" meaning the the last div couldn't be found. Can you please tell me why? 
Removing the `:last` however, results in what I would expect. A "new row" is added to every div. Consecutive clicking on the button lets the number of "new row"s grow exponentially (times two each time). This problem also applies to other tags.

Comment: that fiddle works fine...

Comment: For me too... What is your browser?

Comment: And what happens if you use the CSS selector `:last-child` rather than the jQuery `:last`? The jQuery documentation seems to recommend using the CSS one if at all possible, because it's faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that is indeed a browser-specific problem. I used chromium. With FF however, the problem is solved.